# solving regex with positive lookbehind

Tags: regex, pcre, lookbehind

Regexp problem. I'd like to have the first four strings below matching. Output  should be the 3 characters between `_` and `.` only.

Therefore these will match:

`_20101_Bp16tt20_KG2.asc
_201_Bondp0_KGB.ASC
_2011_rndiep16tt20_232.AsC
_20101_odiep16tt20_ab3.ASC`

and should return respectively `KG2`, `KGB`, `232`, `ab3`.

And these will not match:

`_2_ordep16tt.asc
__Bndt20_pippo_K.asc`

I am able to select the whole block `_KG2.asc`, by doing `((?<=_)(...)(\.(?i)(asc)))`. However, I just want `KG2`. I think I should apply a positive lookbehind, but my tries all failed. Could you help me?

Comment: You need positive lookahead not lookbehind. Try `_\K...(?=\.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `\K` and a positive lookahead:

`_\K[A-Za-z0-9]{3}(?=\.(?i)asc$)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QFI6UK/1)

That would match

- `_` Match literally
- `\K` Forget previous match
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{3}` Match 3 times an upper/lower case character or a digit (Replace with a dot if you want to match any character)
- `(?=\.(?i)asc$)` Positive lookahead to assert that what follows is a dot and asc in lower or uppercase and assert the end of the string

Comment: This matches `_2_ordep16tt.asc` and `__Bndt20_pippo_K.asc`

Comment: :) looks good. Might be nice to include those two lines in your regex demo

Comment: Did not explicitly mention that all matches should not necessarily start with letter `K`. My bad, I should have provided more examples maybe

Comment: @giosans `\K`does not matches the letter `K` literally, but it resets the starting point of the reported match. Ihave added an explanation.

Comment: @giosans this answer works, which you can see at the link. `_\K` functions similarly to `(?<=_)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookahead as well

```
((?<=_)(...)(?=\.(?i)(asc)))
```

See https://regexr.com/40jfa

Answer (score 0):

May be this expression is helping you..

```
'_201_Bondp0_KGB.ASC'.match(/(?<=_)(...)(?=\.)/g)
```